# Routing Error | undefined local variable or method `params' for ContactsController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added the following code into my contacts_controller.rb,

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @contact = Contact.new
    end
    def create
        @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
        if @contact.save
            flash[:success] = "Message Sent."
            redirect_to new_contact_path
        else
            flash[:danger] = @contact.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
            redirect_to new_contact_path
        end
    end
    private
        def contact_params
            params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
        end 

    name = params[:contact][:name]
    email = params[:contact][:email]
    body = params[:contact][:comments]
    ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver
end
```

After saving the code I get an error only on my contacts page,

```
Routing Error
undefined local variable or method `params' for ContactsController:Class

Rails.root: /Users/headlineineed/dev/workspace/Saasapp
```

If i remove the line everything is okay. I am following a tutorial and I have scanned the code and compared them there is not difference that I can see.

Here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  resources :contacts, only: :create
  get 'contacts-us', to: 'contacts#new', as: 'new_contact'
end
```

contact_mailer.rb

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default to: 'EMAIL@gmail.com'
        def contact_email(name, email, body)
            @name = name
            @email = email
            @body = body
            mail(from: email, subject: 'Contact Form Message')
        end
    end
```

Comment: show your full contacts controller

Comment: added full contacts_controller.rb code above

Comment: is that a typo or do you have the code for `name, email, body` and `ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver` on their own, they need to be inside a method

Comment: What file would that be under? new.html.erb? Sorry I am 100% new to this stuff.

Comment: It should be inside `app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb` read more at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html about action mailers

Comment: contact_mailer.rb added to original post.

Comment: so when are you trying to send an email using contact mailer ? when a new contact gets saved ??

Comment: You should wrap the name, email, body vairbales and mail call in it's own method inside the ContactsController and only call it when you have params and want to send the email (I'm assuming this would be in the create action)

Comment: -Subash, when i load the page i get the error, undefined local variable or method `params' for ContactsController:Class \\ I narrowed it down the my contacts_controller.rb which the code starting with name = params, that whole section is what seems to be causing me issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send an email everytime a contact is created then you need to move that code as shown below,

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @contact = Contact.new
    end
    def create
        @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
        if @contact.save
        ContactMailer.contact_email(params[:contact][:name], params[:contact][:email], params[:contact][:comments]).deliver
            flash[:success] = "Message Sent."
            redirect_to new_contact_path
        else
            flash[:danger] = @contact.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
            redirect_to new_contact_path
        end
    end

    private

    def contact_params
        params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
    end
end
```

The problem with your code was that it was outside any method and it was not actually being called by anything, now when a contact is being saved it'll send the email.